# Energy minimization

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization, fitting, nonlinear

I am trying to fit some experimental data, and for that I need to solve the following problems:

**1) Minimize the energy of a system of the following form:**

(Not a code, but editor require it to be so)

```
Energy = (Ku*Sin[phi1] + Ms*B*Cos[alpha - phi1])*
t1 + (Ku*Sin[phi2] + Ms*B*Cos[alpha - phi2])*
t2 + (-J1*Cos[phi1 - phi2] - J2*Cos[phi1 - phi2]^2)
```

for each value of B in a range with some step. (-0.7 to 0.7 in Tesla), taking psi1 and psi2 as variables.

Ms, Ku, t1, t2 are just given values and  J1,J2 idealy should be fitting parameters, but for now I just want to focus on a simple case, just substituting reasonable values for them.

**2) Plug in found equlibrium values into the expression:**

(Not a code, but editor require it to be so)

```
M(B)/Ms = [M1*Cos(Psi1eq- alpha) + M2*Cos(Psi2eq- alpha)]/(M1 + M2)
```

And create interpolated function of B.
Where again M1,M2,Ms,alpha are given and Psi1eq, Psi2eq are angles found in 1)

Here is my intermediate solution:
  (This is the code I run in mathematica)

```
(*Parameters*)    
t1 = 9*10^-3; t2 = 3*10^-3; M1 = 0.890; M2 = 0.625; Ms = 0.824; Ku = 10^-3; 
alpha =  Pi/4; J1 = -0.0002; J2 = 0;
(*Evaluation*)
Ez1 = Ku*Sin[Psi1]^2 - Ms*B*Cos[Alpha - Psi1]; 
Ez2 = Ku*Sin[Psi2]^2 - Ms*B*Cos[Alpha - Psi2]; 
Eex = -J1*Cos[Psi1 - Psi2] - J2*Cos[Psi1 - Psi2]^2;
Etot[Psi1_, Psi2_] := Ez1*t1 + Ez2*t2 + Eex;

minima = Table[{fieldTesla, {Psi1, Psi2} /. 
 Last[FindMinimum[{Etot[Psi1, Psi2] /. B -> fieldTesla, 
    0 <= Psi1 < 2*Pi, 0 <= Psi2 < 2*Pi}, {Psi1, Psi2}]}, {fieldTesla,
 0.7, -0.7, -0.001}];
ApproximationExpr = (M1*Cos[Psi1eq - Alpha] + M2*Cos[Psi2eq - Alpha])/(M1 + M2);
Magnetizationtable = Table[{minima[[i, 1]], ApproximationExpr /. {Psi1eq -> 
   minima[[i, 2]][[1]], Psi2eq -> minima[[i, 2]][[2]]}}, {i, 1,
 Length[minima]}];

Magnetizationfunc = Interpolation[Magnetizationtable];
```

Results have the following form:

```
ListPlot[Magnetizationtable, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Magnetizationfunc[x], {x, -0.7, 0.7}]
```

[image]

As one can see for negative fields, something strange going with numerics and I can't fix it. I have been trying numerical minimum search NMinimize or simply equating derivatives to 0 and doing NSolve. Also changing AccuracyGoal, WorkingPrecission etc.

If I change alpha by Pi keeping everything the same, situation reverses:

```
Plot[Magnetizationfunc[x], {x, -0.7, 0.7}]
```

[image]

I expect graph to be symmetric (atleast for sure for high fields). Some assymetry may be involved approximately for B < 0.01. But definetely not this spikes, especially one them is lower that -1, which is matematically impossible, considering the form of the function in 2.
**How to overcome this?**

**3) (Not the OP, but I would be very appreciate for any help on that**)
Modify the code, so it will be able to fit the data from real experiment with interpolated function mentioned in 2) using J1 and J2 as a parameters (mb even with some constraints).

Data Example:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/azik6tffvug92eo/data%20exa%2Cple%20for%20fitting.txt?dl=0

*Notes:
1) It is my 1st post here, so please don't hesitate to tell me, if I need to add or remove something.
2) I dont mind using other mathematical packages to solve this.*

Comment: Some remarks on your posted code: 1.) `E` is the Euler number; you cannot assign values to it. 2.) Function arguments have to be wrapped in brackets `[]`, not in parentheses `()`. 3.) When defining functions, use `SetDelayed` (`:=`) instead of `Set` (`=`), e.g., it should read `Etot[Psi1_, Psi2_] :=`

Comment: corrected 1,3. I am not sure what you mean about 2nd. If it is about ApproximationFunc it is an expression, not func (sorry for confusion).

Comment: in this expression `[M1*Cos(Psi1eq- alpha) +..` the square brackets are a syntax error.  The left side is illegal as well, so maybe that whole thing is not meant to be code..?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about it. Its just an expression, I substitute values in and make a table out of it. I agree name is confusing, so i will change it. But I don't understand what is the syntax error connected with it

Comment: They are saying that if you try to evaluate `M(B)/Ms = [M1*Cos(Psi1eq- alpha) + M2*Cos(Psi2eq- alpha)]/(M1 + M2)` itself in *Mathematica*, you'll get an error. (Try it yourself!)

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I dont have this line in actuall mathematica code. It is just a formula. What I am running in Mathematica is everything that goes after "Here is my intermediate solution:"